# ASP.NET 5 and EF - Replace child list with LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am working on an API controller for an ASP.NET project, and I have ran into an issue. I have a Computer object with a one-to-many relationship with a Services object. When a Computer is added that has an IP identical to an existing Computer in the database, I want to replace the old Computer's attributes, as well as replace the associated Services collection. However, when I try to replace the Services collection, it adds onto the existing Services instead of replacing it.

**Computer Model**

```
public class Computer
{
    public int ComputerId { get; set; }
    public string Ip { get; set; }
    public string Os { get; set; }
    public IList<Service> Services { get; set; }
        
}
```

**Services Model**

```
public class Service
{
    public int ServiceId { get; set; }
    public int ComputerId { get; set; }
    public int Port {get; set;}
    public int Version {get; set;}
}
```

**Computer Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
...
Computer oldComputer = _context.Computers.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Ip == newComputer.Ip);
if(oldComputer != null) {
   oldComputer.Hostname = newComputer.Hostname;
   oldComputer.Os = newComputer.Os;
   oldComputer.Services = newComputer.Services?.ToList(); //this adds new services to old services collection instead of replacing it
}
```

What changes should I make in order to replace the Services collection instead of adding onto it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load existing entities and then clear the collection and replace with the new ones.

```
Computer oldComputer = _context.Computers.Include(c => c.Service).FirstOrDefault(y => y.Ip == newComputer.Ip);
if(oldComputer != null) {
   oldComputer.Hostname = newComputer.Hostname;
   oldComputer.Os = newComputer.Os;
   oldComputer.Services.Clear();
   oldComputer.Services = newComputer.Services?.ToList(); //this adds new services to old services collection instead of replacing it
}
```

If you can actually do an upsert and delete removed services, it might be more efficient in your case but that bit of model is not apparent to me.

Comment: How would I do it the second way you mentioned? I updated with the services model. Btw, your answer works well.

Comment: Also, it seems like it works on the first Post request, but consecutive post requests add onto the services like before.

Comment: That's a little bit more involved. You need to have identity, check when identities match to update the existing object, add when incoming id is 0 or whatever sentinel value you send from client and delete any whose ids were not found in the incoming list.

Comment: Something is likely holding on to your context. Make it scope restricted to per request.

Comment: sorry if this is obvious question but is there a link that explains how to scope restrict per request?

Comment: Not sure if there's anything exactly like that. This really runs into how your application is doing lifetime management. Is it dependency injection (likely)? You can make your context transient if you are using OOB DI, make it InstancePerLifetimeScope on Autofac, something similar on Unity I guess. The snippet of code you posted doesn't answer any of those questions. You should either update the question or post a new one.

Comment: I changed `oldComputer.Services.Clear()` to `_context.RemoveRange(oldComputer.Services)` and that seems to work as well. Not sure if that is bad practice or not.